# How to setup maxSession in selenium docker

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-grid

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub
docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-chrome
```

Ubuntu 16.04

after these 2 commands, I have successfully setup a selenium hub and a selenium node. however current maxSession of this node is set to 1, I need increase to 5. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the documentation? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#increasing-the-number-of-browser-instancesslots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you use a docker compose file.
Below is a simple example you can use.
Just change the MAX_SESSION and MAX_INSTANCES to what you need.

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: "hub"
    ports:
    - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
      - SCREEN_WIDTH=1920
      - SCREEN_HEIGHT=1080
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=2
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=2
```